# Date picker is not working while using .js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using js  file in .net MVC5 i have  written datepicker code in .js file  Installation.js  my datepicker  code is  not  working.

```
(function() {

    Installation.func.initailElement = function () {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (dt) {

                var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(dt);
                var bDisable = noWeekend[0] ? arrDisabledDates[dt] : noWeekend

                if (bDisable)
                return [false, '', ''];
                else
                return [true, '', ''];
            }, 
            minDate: Installation.func.customDate(), 
            showOn: "both", 
            buttonImage: "~/assets/css/theme/flush-datepicker.gif", 
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
        Installation.func.bindEvents();

    };

})();
```

CODE For Partial  view  I have  included required  .js files in my partial  view.

```
<body>

 <div class="fui-form-body">
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="fui-input-width-2">
 </div> 
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker(...)
```

and not

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker(...)
```

1. Your `<input>` element has Id - datepicker.
2. And include reference to jQuery file above jQuery UI file, in your script tag.